# How to add a random answer to a radio button

Tags: c#, random, radio-button

I am looking to add a piece of code that adds a random answer to a radiobutton but I just cant figure out how to get it to add to the radiobutton so that each time you load it displays a different answer.

How may I go about doing this to get it to work?

The code I have used so far:

```
List<string> answers = new List<string>();
answers.Add("1 Byte");
answers.Add("1 KiloByte");
answers.Add("1 PetaByte");
answers.Add("1 MegaByte");

Random rnd = new Random();
string[] MyRandomArray = answers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

List<RadioButton> rbs = new List<RadioButton>();
rbs.Add(rb1);
rbs.Add(rb2);
rbs.Add(rb3);
rbs.Add(rb4);

foreach (string s in MyRandomArray)
{
    rbs.Add(s.ToString())
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: each time *what* loads?  after you make the Random object global, all you should have to do is set the `rbX.Text` from MyRandomArray; the rest is cruft

Comment: well you're trying to add a `string` to `List<RadioButton>`, don't do that

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: Yes i found out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it to reset each time a new instance of the form is called, use the following constructor inside your form (I've called the form "MainForm" in this example). Firstly, make sure your radio buttons are similarly named. Below I'm going to create them but you should just use the Designer in Visual Studio.

```
private RadioButton rb1;
private RadioButton rb2;
private RadioButton rb3;
private RadioButton rb4;
```

Then use this constructor in your form.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();//Adding the radio buttons to form.
    List<string> awnsers = new List<string>();
    awnsers.Add("1 Byte");
    awnsers.Add("1 KiloByte");
    awnsers.Add("1 PetaByte");
    awnsers.Add("1 MegaByte");
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string[] MyRandomArray = awnsers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < awnsers.Length; i++)
    {
        Controls.Find("rb"+(i+1),true).FirstOrDefault().Text = MyRandomArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your logic for randomization in method that will return List of RadioButton and then call, load, the method each time you need it. It may look something like this:

```
var rbs = GetNewRandomListOfRadioButtons(List<string> answers)
```